# Is it possible to set wget to show the transfer times in milliseconds?

Tags: bash, shell, time, wget, transfer

Generally, wget shows transfer times in seconds. Is there a way I can make it show the time in milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total average transfer rate and the total bytes transferred are also part of the output.

```
2010-02-04 09:18:48 (71.5 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [8105/8105]
```

8105 bytes / 71500000 bytes/sec  ==> 0.0001133566 sec

Comment: That should probably be 71.5 * 1024 * 1024 and not 71,500,000.

Answer (score 6):

You can run `time wget ...` to get a real time estimate for a transfer from start to finish.

Comment: This is not suited for short transfers where establishing the connection may take much longer than the actual transfer.